# Dealing with lost two-factor auth token

Tags: authentication, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to come up with a solution from a web service provider point of view, for a problem of lost 2FA token by a given service user. Let's say a user has lost his token along with emergency backup codes and is asking for help. What would be the best (safest) way to proceed? How to actually verify the user identity without requiring to submit personal data? Some services simply deny access forever in such situations, but that's not an option.

Comment: a third factor?

Comment: @RemusRusanu what would that be? Such factor should in theory be immune to this problem, since it could very well repeat itself.

Comment: You realize this is neverending. 3rd factor could be phone. If user looses all three factors, you need a forth factor. Then a fifth.

Comment: That's the point of this question - is there such way. If the service collected e.g. some personal data, that could be used for auth, but that's not the case.

Comment: Just a suggestion (and full disclosure, I work for Twilio/Authy), but if you [implement your 2FA with Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy) then they have a support team to re verify users in the case of losing access to their account.